# How do I properly write macro documentation if the macro is defined in a module?

Tags: macros, documentation, rust

I defined a macro in a module, and it works fine.
Now, I'm trying to document said macro with an example. [Apparently](https://github.com/steveklabnik/rust/commit/fbc823d1e337e546b5bf7e6fc53f26b51a8583f2), I need to manually specify the crate line to ask for macros:

````
/// ```
/// # #[macro_use] extern crate foo;
/// // Some code
/// ```
````

However, I now get an error saying:

```
error: an `extern crate` loading macros must be at the crate root
```

Apparently the example code is loaded in the macro's module, and does not seem compatible with `macro_use`...

I can't believe everyone writes macros directly in the root module... right?

Answer (score 2):

Well adding a main function did the trick. My example code did not need to run anything (just compile) so I didn't even bother adding a main function, but apparently adding it puts the code in a virtual "crate root", and it accepts the macro_use. Yay!

So what I did is just add :

```
/// # fn main() { }
```

Comment: This seems to be mentioned in the source link you referred to: *Second, we’ll need to add our own `main()` as well*. FWIW, this is because once you start defining top-level items (like `extern crate`), the doc test harness assumes that you want to have full control of the example.

Comment: And a snippet of code without main() is invalid? We can't document how to write libraries?

Comment: examples of code in documentation blocks are automatically compiled **and run**. This is done to ensure that documentation examples stay correct, and is really useful. To run code, a main method is needed. Because you are defining top-level items, the main method is not added for you, as I mentioned previously. If you don't want to compile examples, you can disable compiling individual examples. You can also comment out parts of example code that are uninteresting to show but needed to compile. None of this precludes documenting a library.

Comment: Hmmm... there is the no_run keyword to compile but not run this blocks, but they still require a main() function :(